# Как убрать множество массивов в один массив, чтоб передать в функцию?

Tags: c++, qt

Есть массивы, динамические двумерные, которые формируются в результате математических операций. Мне надо несколько массивов объединить в один и передать в функцию. Много аргументов передающихся в функцию выглядит, криворуко.

```
int i=10000;
double *aX = new double [i];
double *aCxmp = new double [i];
double *aCxmp1 = new double [i];
double *aCxcc = new double [i];
double *aCxcc1 = new double [i];
...
QList<QPointF> TconstSeriesZero;
QList<QPointF> TconstSeriesOne;
QList<QPointF> TconstSeriesTwo;
QList<QPointF> TconstSeriesThree;
QList<QPointF> TconstSeriesFour;
...
TconstSeriesOne.append(QPointF(aX[i],aCxcc[i]));
TconstSeriesZero.append(QPointF(aX[i],aCxmp[i]));
TconstSeriesThree.append(QPointF(aX[i],aCxcc1[i]));
TconstSeriesTwo.append(QPointF(aX[i],aCxmp1[i]));
TconstSeriesFour.append(QPointF(aX[0],aCxcc1[i]));
```

Как TconstSeriesOne,TconstSeriesZero,TconstSeriesThree,TconstSeriesTwo,TconstSeriesFour - эти все серии загнать в одну Tconst и передать одним массивом в функцию Chart
chart.h:

```
#ifndef CHART_H
#define CHART_H
#include <QString>

class Chart
{
public:
    Chart(QString Titel, QString abscissaX, QString ordinatusY, double xMin,double xMax,double yMin,double yMax,Tconst);
    QString Titel,abscissaX,ordinatusY;
    double xMin,xMax,yMin,yMax;
};

#endif // CHART_H
```

Как тут в самой функции достать и обработать этот большой массив Tconst, так чтоб от рисовались все графики 
chart.cpp:

```
.....
Chart::Chart(QString Titel,QString abscissaX,QString ordinatusY, double xMin,double xMax,double yMin,double yMax,Tconst)
{
...
    //![4]
    QLineSeries *diagramaForm6SeriesZero = new QLineSeries;
    diagramaForm6SeriesZero->setName("Диаграмма 1");
    diagramaForm6SeriesZero->append(Form6SeriesZero);
    chart->addSeries(Tconst[0]);
    diagramaForm6SeriesZero->attachAxis(axisX);
    diagramaForm6SeriesZero->attachAxis(axisY);
    //![4]
...
}
```

Comment: ни черта не понятно, что ты хочешь/пытаешься сделать... попробуй объясниться или  в рамках чисто абстрактных понятий или жёстко в терминах c++

Comment: сделайте просто класс, в который добавьте как переменные класса все эти массивы (попутно переделав их в std::vector или QVector). Таким образом передача в функцию будет тривиальна.

Comment: @Fat-Zer  Я хочу объединить несколько массивов в один

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для фиксированного количества списков
Tconst можно определить так:

```
QList<QPointF> *Tconst[]={&TconstSeriesZero,&TconstSeriesOne,&TconstSeriesTwo,&TconstSeriesThree,&TconstSeriesFour};
```

В параметрах функции тогда он будет выглядеть так:

```
Chart(QString Titel, QString abscissaX, QString ordinatusY, double xMin,double xMax,double yMin,double yMax,QList<QPointF> **Tconst)
```

А в самой функции доступ по индексу:

```
chart->addSeries(*Tconst[0]);
```

Для std::vector<>

```
std::vector<QList<QPointF> *> Tconst;
Tconst.push_back(&TconstSeriesZero);
Tconst.push_back(&TconstSeriesOne);
Tconst.push_back(&TconstSeriesTwo);
Tconst.push_back(&TconstSeriesThree);
Tconst.push_back(&TconstSeriesFour);
```

В параметрах функции:

```
Chart(QString Titel, QString abscissaX, QString ordinatusY, double xMin,double xMax,double yMin,double yMax,std::vector<QList<QPointF> *> &Tconst);
```

В теле функции перебор массивов:

```
for(unsigned int i=0;i<Tconst.size();++i)
{
  chart->addSeries(*Tconst[i]);
}
```

Comment: Вроде это хорошее решение, но как получить размер *Tconst? Так *Tconst[]->size();  ошибка: expected primary-expression before ']' token ?

Comment: Как мне пробежаться по всем передаваемым значениям ? В цикле for

Comment: @IvanTriumphov Можно передать отдельным параметром, можно считать константой, если их количество всегда одинаково, а можно ссылки поместить не в массив, а в контейнер типа stl::vector<QList<QPointF> *>, у которого есть метод size(), который выдаёт количество элементов.

Comment: @IvanTriumphov в чём затруднение с циклом for ?

Comment: Не могу определить размер , сколько графиков рисовать должно. Не могли бы вы в ответе переписать как будет с std::vector<QList<QPointF> *> и в for вывести эти все графики ?

Comment: @IvanTriumphov Добавлю.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74025/discussion-between-ivan-triumphov-and-mindcleaner).

Answer (score 0):

Можно по разному, например:

```
 std::generate_n(Tconst, i, [aX]() { static auto ptr = ax; return *ptr++; });
std::generate_n(&Tconst[i], i, [aCxmp]() { static auto ptr = aCxmp ; return *ptr++; });
 std::generate_n(&Tconst[2*i], i, [aCxmp1]() { static auto ptr = aCxmp1; return *ptr++; });
```

ну и т.д.  Но для `Tconst` нужно обеспечить невыход за пределы, поэтому лучше 
его сделать вектором и заносить последовательно в конец вектора

Comment: У меня не получается запихнуть несколько массивов таким образом .ошибка: capture of non-variable 'Gradual_reset::ax'. Если можно по подробней

Comment: а почему у меня получается?...

Comment: да, я ваш вопрос невнимательно прочитал, ну прислушайтесь совету  KoVadim  - думаю он предложил хороший вариант